# JasperServer: Unable to locate the subreport exception

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport, jasperserver

I searched for a couple of days to fix this bug with nothing new.

I had a report which include multi-level subreports everything works fine on `iReport 3.7.5`. I used `subreport.jasper` as subreport expression in the first level & also `subreportA.jasper`, `subreportB.jasper` in the second level & place all (the main report & subreports) in the same path.

The problem raised when I try to deploy it on my `JasperServer`.
When I try to upload the first main report the `iReport` wizard offerd me to attach the first `subreport.jrxml` in resource folder and access it with `repo:subreport.jrxml` or `repo:subreport.jasper`.
Then I manually upload the second level subreports and do the same thing change the subreport expression to `repo:subreportA.jasper` and `repo:subreportB.jasper`.

I got compilation error : `Unable to locate the subreport with expression: ""repo:subreport.jasper"". java.lang.Exception: repo:subreport.jrxml not found.`

I try dozen solution and nothing works. 
using : SUBREPORT_DIR @ the beginning,

using full path : `repo:/Circuit_Reports/Connectivity/Connectivity_files/`,

switch between `.jasper` & `.jrxml`.

using `jasperserver_api_engine_impl_0_fix.jar` in lib folder as a fixation to this bug,

I also searched the database record to be sure that they are in the same folder and have the same parent folder.

Comment: Hi karimhammoda, please accept my answer if it works for you or at least clarifies you understanding. Thx

Answer (score 10):

### Smalltalk before Longtalk ;)

(Of course I don't want to encourage you to read everything of this long detailed post! The **bold markers may already be enough to solve your problems** but I found it worth documenting this tricky stuff in some more detail!)

Since I invested another couple of hours on this (after I resolved it some weeks ago, had a change now, but forgot to document it properly, forgot how I did it and could not retrieve this info again in any form - when uploading and configuring to/in JasperServer) ... here is some aggregated functionality mentioned on various sites regarding subreport referencing, how it works and what one can try ...

(I'll update mine or other findings in here if there hopefully will be some)

### Short cut details / best practices?!<sup>4</sup>

Till maybe Jasper functionality provides a similar "wrapping" solution itself ...

To workaround all the problems related to running the *.jrxml, *.jasper files either locally in Preview mode or remotely on a JasperServer I am now using the following approach which **allows to work with only a single *.jrxml file, that will work locally and remotely without modifications, in a multi-developer environment, supporting independent refactoring of dir structures (paths, names) per environment** (= as it should ;-) ):

- using some [**jasper-utils-*.jar**](https://bitbucket.org/andi1234/jasper-utils)

  - put it in your project (Java) class path (**`Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add`**)
  - put it in your **`../jasperserver/WEB-INF/lib/`** folder
- referencing some custom Jasper Java Scriptlet **`jr.utl.EnvScriptlet`** that does the ugly subreport path/reference magic in your master reports

  - define the `REPORT_SCRIPTLET` by adding an attribute to your master report: **report properties -> Report -> Data Set -> Scriptlet Class: jr.utl.EnvScriptlet**
- using some custom properties file **`jr.utl.properties` or otherwise supplied system properties** (any other way to set the Java system properties would be fine as well and work - where already set up properties will override loaded file properties) to configure the different environments including your

  - current environment information via **`jr.utl.env`** property (prod, myOsUsrName, test, demo, staging, local, ...)

    - which determines how the subreport references must be generated / look like
  - server subreport parent directory property references
  - take e.g. these property file contents and put one per environment here:
  - on your **servers: `../jasperserver/WEB-INF/classes/jr.utl.properties`**

    ```
    jr.utl.env=prod
    mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep1.parentdir=repo:/x/y/z/
    mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep2.parentdir=repo:/x/y/z/
    mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep3.parentdir=repo:/x/y/foobar/
    ```
  - in your **local JasperSoft Studio (Eclipse) Java src/build path**: **e.g. `../myrepproject/src/java/jr.utl.properties`**

    ```
    jr.utl.env=dietrian
    mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep1.parentdir=D:/reporting/src/reports/
    mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep2.parentdir=D:/reporting/src/reports/
    mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep3.parentdir=D:/reporting/src/reports.otherdir/
    ```

    - to achive source modification independency in our environments we parameterized those values and generate them once via some workspace-dependent/user-specific `local.properties` file, based on this idea:

      ```
      |- build.xml                  (containing the ANT build magic)      
      |- build.properties           (containing global properties)      
      |- local.properties           (ignored in version control, e.g. .hgignore, user-specific generated from local.template.properties)
      |- local.template.properties  (source for ANT build task generating the local.properties above)
         |- mycomp.local.proj.reporting.dir=D:/reporting
      |- src/reports
         |- jr.utl.properties           (ignored in version control, user-specificly generated based on template below)
         |- jr.utl.template.properties  (source for ANT build task generating the jr.utl.properties above)
            jr.utl.env=${user.name}
            mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep1.parentdir=${mycomp.local.proj.reporting.dir}/src/reports/
            mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep2.parentdir=${mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep1.parentdir}
            mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep3.parentdir=${mycomp.local.proj.reporting.dir}/src/reports.otherdir/
      ```
- defining your **`BASE_DIR`** master report parameters as e.g. 
  **`$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getProp("mycompany.allsubreports.parentdir")`** (matching some environment-dependent property in your `jr.utl.properties` file)
- defining the master subreport expressions as e.g. **`jr.utl.EnvScriptlet.getSubrepPath( $P{BASE_DIR}, "subrep1.jrxml")`**

  - automatically resolving the values from properties you could also use e.g. these variants:

    - `jr.utl.EnvScriptlet.getSubrepPathByPropKey( $P{BASE_DIR}, "mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep1.name")`
    - `jr.utl.EnvScriptlet.getSubrepPathByPropKeys( "mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep1.parentdir", "mycompany.local.jr.gui.rep.subrep1.name")`
  - `$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getSubrepPath(...)` does not work here :-( (I don't know why)
- do not forget to **restart your server** when you put all the files on the server!

(<sup>4</sup>: Of course I am still seeing some minor improvements here, but it seems much better than all the ugly solutions I found till now. Improvements I would see:

- using the `REPORT_SCRIPTLET` or scriptlet functionality may not be the best way to go, but it will probably work in the vast majority of use cases
- although both existing Jasper classes suggest this they do not seem to be able to handle the above properly:

  - [`FileResolver`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/FileResolver.html)
  - [`RepositoryUtil`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/repo/RepositoryUtil.html)
    )

(<sup>5</sup>: the relevant special handling is encoded here: [EnvScriptlet.java/getSubrepPath(String,String,boolean,String[])](https://bitbucket.org/andi1234/jasper-utils))

### Intro (Background)

First thing to know is that the **handling/setup in JasperStudio** is quite **different from** the handling on **Jasper Server (Repository)**<sup>5</sup> ...

suppose we have the following enviroments:

- our Eclipse install dir: `C:\eclipse\`
- our Eclipse (Report) workspace: `C:\workspace\`
- our report project under: `C:\workspace\report-project\`
- our reports under: `C:\workspace\report-project\src/reports`
- a master report `C:\workspace\report-project\src/reports/masterrep.jrxml`
- some subreport `C:\workspace\report-project\src/reports/subrep1.jrxml`
- another subreport `C:\workspace\report-project\src/reports/somesubdir/subrep2.jrxml`
- the `BASE_DIR` (explained in next section) in our workspace master report is set to `C:\workspace\report-project\src/reports/`
- our Jasper Report Server GUI repo id-path of our master report will be: `/x/y/z/`
  (which is not to-be-confused with the visual named-path, e.g. which could be `Financial Reports/Expenses/Current Year`)

### In general: Jasper Studio, JasperServer

(and other "Jasper runtime environments" like custom Java Jasper package usage):

- it seems a **good practice** to declare a **report parameter** "prefix" which can vary depending on your Jasper runtime environment e.g. named **`BASE_DIR`**

  - important here is that it seems best to **assume the suffixed *`/`* may be included**<sup>1</sup>  because there are cases where you may have/want to use it in a way where it should be an empty or "unslashed" path expression

    - e.g. `$P{BASE_DIR} + "subrep1.jrxml"` which should resolve to
      `repo:subrep1.jrxml`
  - see e.g. [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_create_subreports.htm) for more details (look for `SUBREPORT_DIR`)

(<sup>1</sup>: which I personally find a bad practice in general (not looking at Jasper Reports in this respect) when dealing with directory-like structures)

### JasperStudio Designer (Eclipse Plugin)

(the official IReport successor with loads of more functionality)

(if you do not use the preview functionality this may be uninteresting to you)

- unfortunately I found no practical way to fully support (normal) "team-development" with subreports (and likely other relative resources as well), meaning here the (currently to me unknown) **inexistent possiblity to separate local paths and *.jrxml files** :-(

  - e.g. if you have a version control system in place and work in different environments (different local paths to repos and/or different developers) the **master report has to contain a local path to your subreport in some way**)

    - I tried different approaches that failed:
    - relative path expressions in `BASE_DIR` do not work since the working directory is the eclipse dir, e.g. `C:\eclipse`
    - `Eclipse->Window->Preferences->JasperStudio->Properties->Add` e.g. *my.base.dir*

      - it is not available in the Preview mode, e.g. via `new java.io.File(System.getProperty("my.base.dir")).getCanonicalPath() + "/"` for our `BASE_DIR` expression (these props may be only used by the designer itself, but not set in preview runs)
    - just in case you may stumble upon (as I did): `Eclipse->Window->Preferences->JasperStudio->Report Execution->Virtualizer Temporary Path` is something unrelated (not useful here) dealing with the storage of the report result "caching"
    - of course I could write an ANT task to replace these local pattern based on a regexp filter copy on every usage/checkout, but that seems not a good way to handle this
- if you solely want to work with **`*.jrxml` files** (as I do<sup>3</sup>) you have to reference some `subrep1.jrxml` like this: **`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport($P{BASE_DIR} + "subrep1.jrxml")`**

(<sup>3</sup>: I don't need the `*.jasper` files explicitely and do not see why I want to deal with them. BTW the JasperServer WebGUI only seems to support the upload of `*.jrxml` files)

### JasperServer Web GUI

(e.g. provided by some Tomcat application server and storing its data in some postgres database)

### Scenario 1: reference attached subreport resource(s)

- if you do not want to reuse your report in general, it seems fine to add your supreport to your master report (so it is not visible in the GUI repo tree - see below subitem how you could reference it outside of your master anyways)
- if you attach your subreport it should in general have its **file name as its resource id**, e.g. our `subrep1.jrxml` from above is uploaded with a resource id of `subrep1.jrxml` (thus making the handling of local design references and server references less complicated)
- taking the example reports from above we have to set our **`BASE_DIR` to `repo:` in the to-be-uploaded master report**

  - thus the subreport expressions `$P{BASE_DIR} + "subrep1.jrxml"` and `$P{BASE_DIR} + "somesubdir/subrep2.jrxml"` should work on the server as well
  - NOT recommended!: you could still reference these reports from other reports with absolute paths like this<sup>2</sup>: `repo:/x/y/z/masterrep.jrxml_files/masterrep.jrxml_`

(<sup>2</sup>: which I would not recommend in this case; it's undocumented and may change; better put your subreports then into the "GUI repo path" as described below)

### Scenario 2: reference repo subreport resource(s)

- suppose we upload our subreports to the master repo id-path `/x/y/z/` (as shown on top)
- again we have to differentiate **two different use cases**

  - we do **NOT** want to use the **subreport as a standalone report** (it will always only be included in other master reports)

    - in this case we should upload it using **`Add Resource->File->JRXML`** and reference it
    - `../subrep1.jrxml` or `./subrep1.jrxml` do not work since it seems the **underlying logic cannot handle the relative path expression `..`** (and **likely `.` not** as well) (which would actually be nice :-( )
    - so what we have to do here is to supply an **absolute canonical path** in the **`BASE_DIR`** of our masterrep.jrxml, **e.g. `repo:/x/y/z/`**
  - we want to use the **subreport as a standalone report** as well

    - in this case we should upload it using **`Add Resource->JasperReport`**
    - this obviously creates a hidden folder `repo:/x/y/z/subrep1.jrxml_files` containing the report itself and other resources
    - that's why we not only have to **adjust the `BASE_DIR` (as above)**, but also the subreport expression to, **e.g. `$P{BASE_DIR} + "subrep1.jrxml_files/subrep1.jrxml_"`** (which points to the subreport itself)
  - and **maybe remove the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(...)` wrapper function**, because the server does this automatically **for `*.jrxml` files**
  - I did not fully investigate some other likely incorrectly used approaches which did not work for me to solve the mentioned problems (maybe somebody else has some outcome/corrections here):

    - `$P{REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER}.resolveFile("subrep1.jrxml")` (NullPointerException)
    - resulting in empty subreport sections in master report:

      - `$P{REPORT_CONTEXT}.getRealPath("subrep1.jrxml")`
      - `$P{REPORT_CONTEXT}.getProperty("REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER").resolveFile("subrep1.jrxml")`

### Additional hints

Since I like to **automate the report design and deployment process** as much as it makes sense I wrote some **ANT tasks** that handle the local *.jrxml file to deployable *.jrxml file transformations regarding the `BASE_DIR` and the other transformations.

**SQL** helpful to easily investigate the resource id path structures in a **jasper server postgres meta database** (following something like `jdbc:postgresql://myjasperhost/jasperserver` connecting e.g. with the postgres user):

```
select
    f.id as folder_id,
    r.id as res_id,
    case when f.hidden = true then 1 else 0 end as hidden,
    f.uri||case when f.uri = '/' then '' else '/' end||coalesce(r.name,'') as res_uri,
    r.resourcetype,
    r.creation_date,
    r.update_date,
    f.uri,
    r.name,
    -- less important
    r.version,
    r.parent_folder,
    r.childrenfolder,
    f.parent_folder,
    f.version,
    f.name
-- select *
from jiresourcefolder f
    left outer join jiresource r on (r.parent_folder = f.id)
where not f.uri like '/themes%'
order by f.uri||coalesce(r.name,'')
```

## Related Questions

Questions on the Jaspersoft forum related to this one include:

- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/525466/proper-way-include-subreports
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/530526/subreport-could-not-load-object-location
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/517832/subreports-ireports
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/537611/sub-report-jrxml-jasper
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534861/unable-compile-master-report-pls-advise
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/817852/databasetimezone
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/819343/comjaspersoftjasperserverapijsexception-error-filling-report-and
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/536251/solved-subreport-not-running-jasperserver
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/536218/resolved-problem-subreport-reference-after-exporting-ireport-jasperserver#81141
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527109/subreport-problem
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/522331/atomatically-compile-subreports

Comment: I simplified the answer by providing some *.jar functionality via  the jasper utils package. Further simplifications/modifications could thus be hidden in there.

Comment: It is **even easier** (without jasper-utils.jar) with the use of **report-specific resource bundles** (contain specific properties like subreport paths etc. referable via **`$R{subrep1.parentdir}`**), report-unit-**attached jars** (no global server restarts for changes/updates needed) while all of them can be also **linked resources** and thus easily reusable, avoiding redundancy. I'll update my answer accordingly later.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this mechanism works in all cases but it certainly works for `JasperSoft Studio 5.6.0` and `Jasper Reports Server 5.6.0`.

Essentially we need a simple way to detect that we are running on the server - I use the presence (or absence) of the `$P{REPORT_CONTEXT}` parameter which experiments show is present on the server but not present during preview.

```xml
<parameter name="OnServer" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Are we running on server]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf($P{REPORT_CONTEXT}!=null)]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Once you have that you can then define the location of your subreport from a choice of two:

```xml
<parameter name="SubReportProducts" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[The products subreport]]></parameterDescription>
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{OnServer}.booleanValue() ? "repo:OrderPicksheetProducts.jrxml" : "OrderPicksheetProducts.jasper"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

And then include the sub report:

```xml
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SubReportProducts}]]></subreportExpression>
```

You can then use `Preview` in studio and all still works when you deploy to server.

Comment: This answer was helpful to me. However, I am not using Jasper Reports Server (so I cannot use parameter `REPORT_CONTEXT` to decide whether I am on server), I am reading the `JasperReport` instance from the database and I set it in the Java code as a parameter `SUBREPORT`. My `subreportExpression` is `$P{SUBREPORT} != null ? $P{SUBREPORT} : "subreport.jasper"`. Such a JRXML report and its subreport work for me in both, the Java code and the JasperSoft Studio 6.3.1 without any JRXML changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% of this answer but : You have to upload your subreport as a jrxml ressource and put "repo://subreport.jrxml" to get it work. 
If you read this one of those days tell me if it worked or what solutions you found.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the extension completely and use "repo:/subreportFolder/subreportName". The main report pulls the jasper file in iReport, but on the jasperserver you upload the jrxml.