# Jasper Report Not Working When Deploy war file on apache server

Tags: java, apache, jsp, jasper-reports

I have created jasper report and it woks perfectly on netbean but when i build war file and deploy it on apache server then it not works....

I Tried So hard on this problem spend whole day but didn't find any solution please help me out to solve this

**Here is My Code**

```
String loc = "C:\\Program Files\\report\\
public void CustBillPrint(String BillNo) {
        String path = loc + "customer-bill-1.jasper";
        Map param = new HashMap();
        param.put("billno", BillNo);
        try {
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path, param, con);
            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);

        } catch (JRException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

**I already tried many ways are as follows:**

```
InputStream path = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("report/farmpati-1.jasper");

InputStream path = new FileInputStream(new File("web/report/farmpati-1.jasper"));

InputStream path = new FileInputStream(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/reports/logReport.jrxml");

String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\report\\";

String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "/web/report/";
```

**And All This Alternative Work in NetBan But not working on apache when deploy as war**

Answer (score 0):

Use `ServletContext`'s `getResourceAsStream()` method to read a resource in a jar file in any web application..

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/farmpati-1.jasper");
```

please have look  into [Reading files in jar](http://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-and-war-files-java-and-webapp-archive/)

Answer (score -1):

I have found a possible answer on community.jaspersoft.com:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/536218/resolved-problem-subreport-reference-after-exporting-ireport-jasperserver

> "In the report that's working, the subreport isn't just in the
>   repository as its own report on the same level as the main report. 
>   There is also a copy of that subreport in the Resources "folder" for
>   the main report."

---

That topic contains more than 1 solution, one of them is a resolved topic here on Stackoverflow:
[JasperServer: Unable to locate the subreport exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364205/jasperserver-unable-to-locate-the-subreport-exception/20374515#20374515)
(warning: this is a very long, but detailed, read)

Comment: Please read an article on [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) In your answer you have only links and it's not enough to be a good answer. Write more information about the solution you found and/or cite the sources in the answer.